# How to call Sheet Variable Sheet names via converting to text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

My Google sheet file has sheets named 1985, 1986, 1987...
I thought I'd be clever by trying to call $B$27 of each sheet through this ='TEXT(1984+COLUMN(A1),"0")'!$B$27 to equate to '1985'!$B$27. The Column(A1) exists as a counter to go from 1985 to 1986 to 1987...
What is the proper syntax to convert the number into text for a sheet-name?
Thank you for the help!
Respectfully,
Ross

Answer (score 0):

read about the Indirect() function.
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en

```
=INDIRECT((1985+COLUMN(A1)-1)&"!B27")
```